# Consult mails (cURL)

Tags: bash, email, curl, pop3

I would like to consult my mails. I wrote this code :

```
curl -u  user@live.com:mdp --ssl pop3s://pop-mail.outlook.com:995/ -o ./email.txt
```

It returns a list with size of all mails. I would like to get a list of the content of all mails. What command should I use ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not use somethink like [fetchmail](http://www.fetchmail.info/) or [getmail](http://pyropus.ca/software/getmail/) which are more appropriate tools? Otherwise it seems to be something like `curl -v -u user:password --ssl pop3s://pop-mail.outlook.com:995/1`

Comment: Because I didn't know those tools until now lol. ...:995/1 returns the content of the last mail actually. I thought using a loop while until the  command `curl .... :995/$variable`return an error (which is "curl: (56) Failure when receiving data from the peer")